# User permissions in WMI

Tags: security, wmi

Does anyone know which WMI Class is to be used to getting information of which users or user groups have permission for a given folder?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to to get and set file permissions via WMI; [here's a MS Scripting Guys article with explanation and examples](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.05.scriptingguy.aspx).

...but there are so many better/easier ways to manage security, from [CACLS](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-1050976.html)/[XCACLS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/825751) to [ADSecurity.dll](http://flylib.com/books.php?ln=en&n=2&p=21&c=209&p1=1&c1=1&c2=242&view=2) and more.